# How to remove xfce4 and switch to KDE under vncserver?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, xfce, vnc

I have installed tigervnc server and xfce

```
 sudo apt install xfce4 xfce4-goodies
```

and was working for some time. Then I decided to try KDE and did

```
sudo apt install kubuntu-desktop
sudo apt remove xfce4
```

But nevertheless I have `xfce4` on vnc screen. How to remove it and switch to KDE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`apt show xfce4` indicates that `xfce4` is a metapackage. By running `sudo apt remove xfce4` you don't achieve removal of the packages specified by `xfce4`.

If you want to remove all the packages specified by the `xfce4` metapackage, go through the appropriate history.log file, or the archived version, in `/var/log/apt/` and remove the relevant packages.